# issue with finding differentiation

Tags: integration, derivatives

How to find the differentiation of this

$$fx =\int_1^x \sqrt{(t^4 - 1)}dt$$

I am supposed to find the length from 2-5

I know that the differentiation of the integral of the function is the function itself. But I am not sure how to deal with the limits here.

Comment: Same question with an answer can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634883/finding-the-length-of-the-part-of-the-graph/3634888#3634888)

Comment: -1, duplicate as pointed out in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

As $$f'(x)=\sqrt{x^4-1},\tag{1}$$

the length of the curve is

$$\int_2^5\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx=\int_2^5\sqrt{x^4}dx=\int_2^5x^2dx=\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_2^5=...\tag{2}$$

Remark :

About (1) : please note that variable $t$ has been replaced by the variable $x$ (upper bound).

About (2) : see [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ArcLength.aspx).